# resharper 4.5 making VS2008 very slow especially with ASPX pages

Tags: visual-studio-2008, performance, resharper-4.5

I am using Visual studio 2008 with Resharper 4.5 add-in. the Visual studio performs well on its own, but when I add resharper it slows down and VS freezes for a while every time I type and save the code. the performance is even worse when I am typing and saving aspx files (mark-up or javascript). the solution has around 35 projects in it. my PC RAM is 2GB and the processor is Pentium(4) 3Ghz and the OS is Windows XP. I do want to use resharper, it has some cool features, but at the same time I don't want to be wasting time due to slow performance. any suggestions please?

regards,
Rama

Comment: 2GB on a Pentium 4 3GHz is kind of, well, ancient for a VS2008 developer machine. It's not even dual core, is it? You might do yourself a favor and upgrade to at least 4GB memory and a dual or quad core. 35 projects, on the other hand, is a lot to handle, but that problem may also fade away with a faster system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to try is to turn off solution wide analysis in `ReSharper -> Options -> Settings -> Analyze errors in whole solution`. This will stop ReSharper collecting analysis problem across all files in your solution that you do not have open.

If it is still slow, try turning off code analysis altogether (the checkbox labelled "Enable code analysis" in the same options page). This will however disable the analysis gutter with its errors and warnings - something I think is a key feature of ReSharper.

If you just want to disable analysis on a single file after opening (ie. such as an ASPX file or a large code file), `Ctrl+8` will toggle analysis on and off just for the current file.

Comment: thanks for the suggestions. ctrl+8 is not working for me. I can still see the resharper doing some analysis by showing an icon in the top right hand corner of the editor window. am I missing something?

Comment: You might have a different key binding. Try going to `Tools -> Options -> Keyboard` and seeing what key combination is mapped to `ReSharper_EnableDaemon`.

Comment: thanks. I found that the keyboard shortcuts was set to "None" in resharper option. I changed it to use resharper shortcuts, then it worked fine. thanks.